# Why TFS doesn't add some DLL in Bin Directory?

Tags: tfs

When I added a whole solution in TFS, it didn't add one dll, I then have to add it manually.

Is there something that prevents it from doing so ?

Comment: You need to clarify your question to get an answer. i.e. did 1/1 DLL's get skipped or was there just 1/20 that was skipped? Also, you should generally avoid checking in DLL's because they are large and performance can decline.

Comment: As I said I did add a whole solution so with all dlls, so 1/10 wasn't added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering only 1 DLL was rejected out of several, it sounds like a TFS bug.  I know don't be shocked... there are actually a few of these.

For example, I have text files get removed from my solution when I use "undo checkout". Unfortunately that problem is unpredictable, so no fix yet.

TIP: Always diff your solutions and projects before you check them in.

Answer (score 2):

How did you add the solution?  The Add Items button will exclude a number of items through the filters you see in the dialog.  There are two tabs there : Included & Excluded.  When adding things to source control this way, you'll need to check the excluded tab for anything caught by the filter like 3rd party libraries.

If you used Add Solution to Source Control, I'm not entirely sure.  If the dlls were in a project or a solution folder they should have been added.  Again, if you give more details (step by step) I can help a little more.

Comment: I don't remember exactly what I did so I'll live with it thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan said when adding to the repository certain filers are applied, e.g. you have to *explicitly* add dlls to the repos. See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/63904b5e-2dab-4489-9364-583a43bc7eac)

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that you have binded the project to IIS. And IIS block access to some DLLs.**

If you using Visual Studio 2012 and you can't add the files to TFS just exclude a file, add to repository, include file and check in.